# Substitude similar symbols

Tags: replacement, filtering

In the examplary list

```
\[Delta]para = {\[Delta]u1, \[Delta]u2, \[Delta]u3, \[Delta]u4, \[Delta]w2, \[Delta]w3, \[Delta]w4, \[Delta]al1, \[Delta]al2, \\[Delta]al3, \[Delta]al4}
```

I would like to replace the symbols `\[Delta]u[i]->F1,\[Delta]w[i]->F2,\[Delta]a[i]->F3`

to get in this case `{F1,F1,F1,F1,F2,F2,F2,F3,F3,F3,F3}`

How to solve this problem for general list ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first two characters of the symbols have to be compared, you could write

```
Map[Symbol[StringTake[SymbolName[#],2]]/.{\[Delta]u->F1,\[Delta]w->F2,\[Delta]a->F3}&,\[Delta]para]
```

Comment: Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the F1, F2, F3 are symbols, you could do something like this:

```
Symbol /@ StringReplace[SymbolName /@ \[Delta]para, 
  {"\[Delta]u" ~~ __ -> "F1", "\[Delta]w" ~~ __ -> "F2", "\[Delta]a" ~~ __ -> "F3"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your support